# Assign multiple variables at once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was wondering if I could assign multiple variables to one object without having to assign it to a variable then assign them. So for example is it possible to convert this:

```
GameObject obj = Pooler.Instantiate().GetComponent<Asteroid>();
obj.speed = speed;
obj.direction = -1;
```

To look something like this:

```
Pooler.Instantiate().GetComponent<Asteroid>().({speed = speed, direction = -1});
```

When I do that, I get an error, so I was wondering if it was possible to do something like that?

Comment: You can use that syntax as part of object initialization, for example `new Asteroid {speed = 0, direction = 1}`, but only then. Seems like it's not possible in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Assigning multiple variables at once" would be called **object initializers** in C#. Here is a classic example:

*Old way:*

```
   Person person = new Person();
   person.FirstName = "Scott";
   person.LastName = "Guthrie";
   person.Age = 32;
```

*New way:*

```
var person = new Person { FirstName="Scott", LastName="Guthrie", Age=32 };
```

Both syntaxes include the keyword "`new`".

Comment: @TheBoogieMan yes, that's correct, this is called object initializer syntax.